# How to make the ajax load on the scroll to about 90% instead of scrollbar reaching the bottom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

Here is the code sample and I its working all perfectly just the case  is it loads further ajax request when the scroll bar hits the bottom, I want to make it load when it may reach upto 90% and beyond that form top.

```
$count = sql::read("SELECT COUNT(table_column_name) as count FROM table_name WHERE Info ='".$info."'");
$actual_row_count = $count[0]->count;

<script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function(e) {
            var page = 1;
            var flag = 0;
            $(window).scroll(function () {
                $('#more').hide();
                $('#no-more').hide();
                if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 200) {
                    $('#more').css("top","400");
                    if(flag == 0)
                    {
                        $('#more').show();
                    }
                }
                if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
                    $('#more').hide();
                    $('#no-more').hide();
                    page++;
                    var data = {
                        page_num: page,
                        info : '<?php echo $info; ?>'
                      };
                    var actual_count = "<?php echo $actual_row_count; ?>";
                     if((page-1)* 12 > actual_count){
                        $('#no-more').css("top","400");
                        $('#no-more').show();
                        flag = 1 ;
                    }
                    else{
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "data.php",
                            data:data,
                            success: function(res) {
                                $("#result").append(res);
                                console.log(res);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to calculate if bottom of current viewport beyond 9/10 of total document height or not. Consider following expression, it might help:

```
($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) / $(document).height() > 0.9
```

---

However, you main problem caused by the fact that scroll event fires multiple time per second. Therefore it make all possible calls before single ajax request has been resolved. You need to unattach event handler before making first call and reattach it after ajax succeed.

For example:

```
var win = $(window);
function onScroll() {
    ...
    if (90% document scrolled) {
        win.off('scroll', onScroll);
        $.ajax({
            ...
            success: function(res) {
                $("#result").append(res);
                win.on('scroll', onScroll);
            }
        });
    }
}
win.on('scroll', onScroll);
```

Comment: its working for .9 but it is loading rest all the listing in one go now,, not having the pagination effect anymore now

Comment: if this condition is working fine why its loading all the data, though in data.php I have called the 12 values each time

Comment: That is because `scroll` event fires multiple time per second. Therefore it make all possible calls before single ajax request has been resolved. You need to unattach event handler before making first call and reattach it after ajax succeed.

Comment: ya i can cchk that in console, how to process with event handle, please suggest?